# Is it possible to have nested ReWrite Conditions in htaccess?

Tags: .htaccess

I have the following situation where I want to have nested ReWrite Conditions, and I have come across a situation where I am not able to see a proper documentation for the same.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(robots.txt|favicon|ico)$ [NC]
RewriteRule . - [S=3]
# Nested ReWrite Condition 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www
    RewriteRule .* http://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

RewriteRule .* http://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI_1} [R=301,L]
RewriteRule .* http://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI_2} [R=301,L] # and so on
```

Therefore, the question comes up that whether the number of skip rules will comprise of the nested ReWrite Conditions, that is, in this case, should the number of skipped rewrite rules be 4 or 5(if including the rewrite condition).

Comment: What exactly is it that you're trying to do? What's `%{REQUEST_URI_1}` supposed to be?

Comment: its just a re-write rule that I have written as an example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay as you only have posted an example, I show you an example how it works. It's with comments, but if you still don't find it speaking enough, there is a lot more explanation available [here](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/flags.html#flag_s).

```
# Does the file exist?
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
# Create an if-then-else construct by skipping 3 lines if we meant to 
# go to the "else" stanza.
RewriteRule .? - [S=3]

# IF the file exists, then:
    RewriteRule (.*\.gif) images.php?$1
    RewriteRule (.*\.html) docs.php?$1
    # Skip past the "else" stanza.
    RewriteRule .? - [S=1]
# ELSE...
    Rewri
```

This should solve your issue. If not, please update your example in the question so it's clear what you're missing.

And yes, it skips *Rules* and not *Conditions*.

Answer (score 2):

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(robots.txt|favicon|ico)$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www
RewriteRule .* - [S=3]

# the following rules are run only if the first 2 conditions don't match
RewriteRule .* http://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
RewriteRule .* http://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI_1} [R=301,L]
RewriteRule .* http://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI_2} [R=301,L]
```

notice the `!` negation in the 2nd cond
[documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/rewrite/flags.html#flag_s):

> This technique is useful because a RewriteCond only applies to the
>   RewriteRule immediately following it. Thus, if you want to make a
>   RewriteCond apply to several RewriteRules, one possible technique is
>   to negate those conditions and add a RewriteRule with a [Skip] flag.

Comment: yep.. I knew about the not condition with skip re-write rules, but didn't think abt using both conditions one after the other